# how can i write code for store image in sdcard?

Tags: android

I want to store image in sdcard using android coding,Anybody know the code for image store in sdcard using Android coding..

Thanks All

Answer (score 1):

Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get a `File` object pointing to the root of external storage (which may or may not be an "sdcard"). From there, use standard Java file I/O.